# Getting Maven issue

Tags: maven

Getting Maven issue, below is the issue that I am getting:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6:
>   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org:
>   Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]

I have `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` in the same folder, where I am running the **mvn package** command. Please help.

Comment: Proxy/Firewall issue cause the host could not resolved...

Comment: Firewall is open for that port number....

Comment: But you seemed to be need a proxy access cause `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org ` shows that...

Comment: It was issue with settings.xml file in conf file. I am able to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with incorrect configuration in settings.xml which I have corrected and now everything is working fine.